# Can't test iOS application in Instruments?

Tags: ios, instruments

I want to test my iOS application through Instruments, When i click the Record Button in Instruments, Suddenly My iOS application is getting CRASH , It says "SIGKILL". Xcode version : 5.1 and I am testing the iOS app in Simulator.

Comment: Just a note, you shouldn't be doing performance profiling on the simulator. It's not much like a real device in terms of speed.

Comment: tanq for you suggestion. Bu How can i do it on Simulator? do you have any idea?